# SQL Error: "-" can not be applied to timestamp

Tags: python, sql, presto

I am using the following SQL query statement to compute time difference in minutes.

```
query_preadm_uo = """
select distinct oe.icustay_id, 
                date_diff('second', timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00', oe.charttime) as charttime, 
                oe.itemid, oe.value ,  
                60*24*date_part('day',ic.intime-oe.charttime)  + 
                60*date_part('hour',ic.intime-oe.charttime) + 
                date_part('min',ic.intime-oe.charttime) as datediff_minutes
from mimiciii.outputevents oe, mimiciii.icustays ic

"""
```

I am getting the following error.

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:167: '-' cannot be applied to timestamp,
>   timestamp unable to rollback

The error is in the following part of the code.

```
60*24*date_part('day',ic.intime-oe.charttime)  + 60*date_part('hour',ic.intime-oe.charttime) + date_part('min',ic.intime-oe.charttime) as datediff_minutes
```

Is there anyway I can get rid of this error by correcting the above part of code in my query and write some other to achieve the same functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

Changed for `Presto`, not `PostgreSQL`.

You can simply use

```
DATE_DIFF('minute', ic.intime, oe.charttime) AS datediff_minutes
```

**Original Answer for PostgreSQL**

You can use `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ...)` to convert your timestamps into the number of seconds between the timestamp and the unix epoch, then subtract those values and divide by 60 to get the number of minutes i.e.

```
SELECT ...
       (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ic.intime) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM oe.charttime)) / 60 AS datediff_minutes
...
```

Note you can also substitute:

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM oe.charttime) AS charttime,
```

for

```
date_diff('second', timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00', oe.charttime) as charttime,
```

Comment: I got the following error by doing the changes you mentioned. The error is  `An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: line 1:137: Invalid EXTRACT field: epoch
unable to rollback`

Comment: What is your SQL version?

Comment: I am using AWS Athena to query S3. Amazon Athena uses Presto with ANSI SQL support

Comment: You may want to use [to_unixtime](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#to_unixtime) function

Comment: @ebyhr you are right; you could but given `date_diff` will give the required result directly I don't see much point?

Comment: Yes, date_diff is the right answer. Sorry, I mentioned to Abdul because extract-epoch isn't supported in Presto.

Comment: @ebyhr yeah - the question was originally tagged for PostgreSQL which does support extract-epoch. Once I found out it was Presto I updated to `date_diff`.